# How to change all rows except one in SQL

Tags: sql

I have to increment a reaction every time a user clicks it and also the user can only have one reaction to each post so if he chooses another reaction it should undo the other one and increment new one.

Right now I am using this statement but this sets it to 1

Is there any way I could store the previous selection and decrement it and then use this statement

```
$sql="UPDATE Reaction_User SET $te = 1 WHERE EMAIL ='$eml' AND ID = $i";
```

`$te` is the reaction name (eg like, haha etc.)

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the problem is.  You're currently setting a value to `1`.  What do you *want* to set the value to?

Comment: I actually want to query first to check if there is any row with value greater than 1

Comment: So you're asking how to select data?  Something like this?:  `SELECT $te FROM Reaction_User WHERE EMAIL='$eml' AND ID = $i`

Comment: Kind of but I only want the Rows which have value greater than 1 this would return all the rows

Comment: So add `AND $te > 1` to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Okay and how would I change the values of the returned rows

Comment: You update rows with an `UPDATE` statement, like you have.  Are you just looking to add `AND $te > 1` to the `WHERE` clause on your `UPDATE` statement?  It's really not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: Sorry I am just new to mysql so its all confusing 
what i want to do is Change the value of rows to 0 whose value is greater than 0 and at the same time I want to store the name of the row updated or changed to 0

Comment: You might be taking the wrong approach to your overall goal.  Think of it in terms of the current state of the data and the desired state of the data.  Maybe provide a sample of those states in the question.

Comment: So I will explain the overall situation
I am creating a blogging website where a user can login and see other people posts and can have any of the six reactions which include like,sad,angry,haha,wow,love but each user can only have 1 reaction to each post so if a user first selects like then increment like counter in the total likes for that post but if the user then has a different reaction to the same post then previous selection should be decremented and the new selection should be increased in total of that particular reaction counter